# Is there a Linux alternative for AutoHotkeys?

Tags: linux, hotkeys

Is there a Linux alternative for AutoHotkeys? (or something to create hotkeys and text expansion?)

Answer (score 1):

Try [IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/), though it's not quite as powerful as AHK is.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoKey](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1052846) is an option.